# Passport.js custom error for unauthorized and bad request

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, jwt, passport.js

Implemented `passport-jwt` and trying to throw custom error response if user is false(email|password empty`) 
And if the user is not registered

api.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const router = require('express-promise-router')();

const passportHelper = require('../helpers/passportHelper');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const { badRequest } = require('../helpers/responseHelper');

const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
const requireSignin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if(!user) {
        const err = new Error('please provide email and password.');
            err.status = 400;
            err.code = 'CP_SI_ValidationFailed';
            return err;
    }
});

router.post('/signup', authController.signup);
router.post('/signin', requireSignin, authController.signin);

module.exports = router;
```

when i tryed to signin with postman i'm not getting any response

expected result

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "CP_SI_ValidationFailed",
        "message": "email and password is required"
    }
}
```

is there any other way to handle badRequest and return above resonse ,

thank you

Answer (score 7):

Here's an updated answer that does return a response.

```js
const requireSignin = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      const err = {};
      err.status = 400;
      err.code = 'CP_SI_ValidationFailed';

      return res.json(err); // send the error response to client
    }
    return next(); // continue to next middleware if no error.

  })(req, res, next); /* passport.authentication returns a function,
                         we invoke it with normal req..res arguments 
                         to override default functionality */ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning an error from passport.authenticate callback is not enough. The returned value is not handled by passport. If you want to return a custom error to the client, you should write a custom middleware. It should work as expcted if you change your `requireSignin` method to something like this:

```
const requireSignin = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
        if(err || !user) {
            const err = {};
            err.status = 400;
            err.code = 'CP_SI_ValidationFailed';

            return res.json(err); // send the error response to client
        } 
        return next(); // continue to next middleware if no error.
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time, tried your solution i'm not getting any response at all. so i tried this `console.log('test 1');

    passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {

     console.log('test 2');

        if(err || !user) {
         console.log('test 3');` in the console i can seen only `test 1`.

Comment: You have setup a local strategy already, haven't you? Have a look at passport documentation, on how to setup an local strategy: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Comment: yes i have setup `passport-local` strategy thank you, i have taken an other approach, created a middle ware to validate and to check whether user is registered or not. `router.post('/signin', validateUser, requireSignin, authController.signin);` please provide your inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

For the newest implement, we can do this through [#built-in-http-exceptions](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#built-in-http-exceptions)

Here's my code:

```
  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser({
      account: username,
      password,
    });
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        {
          code: 401,
          message: 'Invalid username or password!, please try again.'
         }
      );
    }
    return user;
  }
```